# iTunes Gift Cards

Tags: itunes, accounts

I live in Japan, with Apple ID details based in Japan. My iTunes account is based in the UK for financial reasons.

I was given an iTunes Gift Card in Japan, and want to upgrade my UK storage (in Pounds).

Can I use this card that is in Yen to buy extra storage in the UK?

Answer (score 4):

From near the bottom of [Redeem and use iTunes Gift Cards and content codes](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201209).

> You can't redeem purchased gifts outside of the country of purchase.
>   For example, an iTunes Gift purchased in France can't be redeemed in
>   an iTunes Store outside of France.

So based on that statement I'd say the answer to your question is no.

However I'd contact Apple directly by calling one of the Apple stores nearest you.

Comment: Tldr; no indeed.

Comment: You probably can make an iTunes account that uses yen and gift the thing you want to the UK account. I don't know how compliant this is with the TOS though.